# C# Закрытие приложения и выполнения кода

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать чтобы при нажатие крестика приложения, выполнялся какой-то код?

В приложении я выполняю эту команду:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectDraw").SetValue("VGABuffer", 0x1433331);
```

После закрытия мне нужно чтобы была выполнена эта команда:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectDraw").DeleteValue("DisableDDSCAPSInDDSD");
```

Comment: Какой тип приложения? Что за код хотите выполнить? Зачем именно вам это?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Отредактировал тему

Comment: Ну давайте еще раз спрошу: какой тип приложения?

Comment: Уважаемый @aepot намекает, что в WinForms приложении, например, можно подписаться на событие "закрытие главной формы". При этом "крестик" есть и у консольного приложения.

Comment: WinForms net fraimork 4.x

Comment: Как подписаться на это событие?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579446/capturing-application-exit-event-winforms

Comment: @Forum4anin _Как подписаться на это событие?_ https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/2.4.php

Answer (score 2):

Вам  в комментарии tym32167 привел правильную ссылку. На более общий способ.

Но, возможно, Вам нужен способ немного проще. Вот этот пример - совсем простой:

```
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Exp2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Closing += ExecuteOnClosing;
            }

            void ExecuteOnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e){
                MessageBox.Show("Меня закрывают!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Как минимум стоит добавить в чём разница между closing и closed

Comment: Чёт я не чего не понял из этого кода :(

Comment: @Forum4anin у формы есть событие ``Closing``, оно вызывается когда форма закрывается, т.е. нажат крестик или по любой другой причине, закрывающей форму. Событие Closing нужно связать с методом ExecuteOnClosing (``Closing += ExecuteOnClosing;``), и при закрытии формы ``ExecuteOnClosing()`` будет выполняться.

Comment: > Чёт я не чего не понял из этого кода :(  - мне кажется, что в этом коде всего 4 строки, котрые "имеют смысл", остальное - шаблонный код. А еще его можно запустить в студии, поставить точки останова и погонять под отладчиком. Я постараюсь дополнить ответ тем, что OnClosing предшествует событию Closed, и имеет параметр, котрый позволяет прервать закрывание программы

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте событие закрытия формы.

```
private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    
    if (MessageBox.Show("Закрыть?", "Внимание!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) == DialogResult.No)
                                    e.Cancel = true;
}
```